# Where to find list of all vendor in the world?

Tags: python, list, networking, nmap, vendor

I'm interested in a list containing all vendors in the world (HP, Samsung, Apple etc...), I found:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-mac-prefixes

But I would like a list from the original source  plus I don't care about mac-address.

The list will be used in python program to check if a string contains a name of a vendor

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: @RonMaupin it's not recommendation it's one source...

Comment: You are asking where to find the list, an off-site resource, and that is off-topic here.